# Converting iOS ABPeoplePicker numbers into valid, canonical number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the iOS ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to allow a user to select a phone number, but the number I get back is formatted like this:

+44 (0) 20 3162 0001

I can strip out the spaces and the parenthesis, but the number that remains isn't really a valid phone number.

Does iOS offer any way to force ABPeoplePicker to return a valid, canonical phone number i.e.

+442031620001

or will I be fored to apply a regex or something to it?

Comment: Are you planning on presenting it to the user to dial? Passing it to the `tel://` URL scheme as-is will work for dialing just fine, if that is what you want.

Comment: It will be sent to an HTTP service we're building.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to apply a regex. but it should just be strip all but optionally + at the beginning

STILL there is no guarantee that'll get you a valid phone number!

e.g. In Addressbook I could write +44 353 1232 (-0 / -1)

to name to alernates